# Animation firing twice when visiting a cached page by Turbolinks 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm using [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and I have a div with the `animated` and `fadeIn` classes. The div fades in fine on initial visit, but when it's visited a second time (i.e. once the page is already cached by turbolinks), the fadeIn animation occurs twice -- once when the cache preview is shown (this happens instantly), and once after the page is actually loaded. How can I fix this and make the animation run only once?

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: @JustinLicata There's really no code to this except the div which is `.login-form-wrapper.animated.fadeIn` so I just added the code from the `application.js` file

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this @arif?